# Can't use my own DLL which uses SFML

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, sfml

I'm making my own game library which uses SFML with VS2013. I want to reuse the code by setting the library as DLL. However, I'm having trouble while using my own DLL.

Here are the detailed descriptions of my situation:

1. Here is part of the code in the game loop where `window` is a `sf::RenderWindow` and `rect` is a object defined in my DLL which simply is just a `sf::RectangleShape` with defined properties ( a small blue rectangle at (0,0)).

   ```
   window.clear(sf::Color::White);
   window.draw(rect);
   window.display();
   ```

   However, after the `window.draw(rect)`, the whole screen will turn into black, even though the above statement should clean it as white and `rect` only occupies a small place at the upper left corner.
2. There should be no problem with my class, since if I paste the class declaration and definition directly into the main source file (of course deleting the stuff like `__declspec(dllexport)`), everything works nicely.
3. All the functions in my DLL which do not use SFML works correctly when loading from the DLL.
4. SFML is statically linked both in the DLL project and the project which uses it.
5. I've viewed and  followed the MSDN to setup my projects.

So how to fix it? I suppose the problem should be that I missed some steps which enable a DLL to use another library, but I didn't find relevant threads (probably I used wrong keywords...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SFML is statically linked both in the DLL project and the project which uses it.

If you do indeed link SFML statically against your DLL, then you'll have a problem, because now your finally application holds a copy of SFML and your DLL holds a copy of SFML. Thus allocated stuff by SFML in the DLL won't be necessarily available in the application and the other way around.

AS a solution you can only link everything dynamic or everything static in the final application. This means you either use the dynamic libraries of SFML or you link your library static as well and only link against SFML static in your application and not in your library.

Since you're using VS 2013 you'll also have to rebuild SFML itself and if you use the latest version the statically linking has changed ([full discussion](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=9362.0)). So here's some ASCII art for how it would work with SFML 2.0 or 2.1.

```
             winmm   gdi32   opengl
              /  \     |     /
             /    \    |    /
            v      v   v   v
   sfml-system-s  sfml-window-s
        |  |         |  |
        |  +---------------+      
        |            |  |  |
        |  +---------+  |  |
        |  |            |  |
        v  v            v  v
  example.exe <--- yourlib.dll
```

With SFML from source (target 2.3), it would looks something like this.

```
       sfml-system-s  sfml-window-s  winmm  gdi32  opengl
                |         |           |       |      |
   +------------+ +-------+           |       |      |
   |            | | +-----------------+       |      |
   |  +-----------+ | +-----------------------+      |
   |  |         | | | | +----------------------------+
   |  |         | | | | |
   v  v         v v v v v
yourlib.dll -> example.exe
```

What you essentially want however is this:

```
sfml-system-s  sfml-window-s  winmm  gdi32  opengl  yourlib-s
         |         |           |       |      |       |
         | +-------+           |       |      |       |
         | | +-----------------+       |      |       |
         | | | +-----------------------+      |       |
         | | | | +----------------------------+       |
         | | | | | +----------------------------------+
         | | | | | |
         v v v v v v
         example.exe
```

Dynamic linking essentially works already like the last diagram (just different), thus the dynamic linking works fine "out of the box".

There's a lot of information around the web how linking works etc. One example would be [this forum post](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=7281.msg48091#msg48091).

Comment: Thanks. I tried link everything dynamically and it works. Never thought it was the problem of static linking and dynamic linking... Should have a deeper understanding of how the linking works.

Comment: I'm glad it works now. I've added some diagrams to maybe help you understand what's going on. Also if you consider it as answer, please mark it as such.